# Is there any way to not to loop this

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have the following code that uses monthly data:

```
set.seed(2)
vector <- as.data.frame(runif(120)+0.5)
b <- data.frame()

    for (j in 1:I(nrow(vector))) {
        if (is.na(vector[j, i]) || is.na(vector[j + 12, i]) || 
            is.na(vector[j + 24, i]) || is.na(vector[j + 36, i]) ||
            is.na(vector[j + 48, i]) || is.na(vector[j + 60, i])) {
            b[j, i] <- NA
        } else if (vector[j, i] < 1 && vector[j + 12, i] < 1 && 
            vector[j + 24, i] < 1 && vector[j + 36, i] < 1 && 
            vector[j + 48, i] < 1) {
            b[j, i] <- vector[j + 60, i]
        } else {
            b[j, i] <- NA
        }
    }
```

It first checks if any of the values are NA (they won't be in this example), and then checks if the value after a year is larger than one. Is there any way to for example use dplyr to get the same result? The problem is that the values are twelve months away from each other, but they need to be checked every month.

Comment: Check out dplyr's "lead" and "lag" functions. Try combining with "group_by(year)" first.

Comment: Looks like you will be getting (semantic) errors when trying to access along the entire extent of the dataframe. `vector[j + 48, i]` won't exist when you are at `j = nrow(vector)-47`. `is.na` will then return TRUE. So you will get TRUE for all the tests in the last 60 rows. The code as presented just throws an error (related to attempting `if(NA){.} `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite clear (to me) what output you're going for here, but dplyr's "lead" function should be able to do this, and should save you a bunch of the NA checking as well.

If you just want to get the year-ahead value, with NAs if there is no year-ahead value, this ought to do it:

```
vector <- data.frame(obs = runif(120)+0.5) # giving this variable a name for 
convenience
vector %>% 
  mutate(year_later = lead(obs, 12),
         two_years_later = lead(obs, 24)) # etc
```

I'm putting that all in one dataframe, but of course you could keep your `b <- data.frame()` if you prefer.

This should replicate your original for-loop, although I'm not getting any observations that match your conditions:

```
vector %>% 
  mutate(final_answer = 
           ifelse(obs < 1 && lead(obs, 12) < 1 && lead(obs, 24) < 1 && lead(obs, 36) < 1 && lead(obs, 48) < 1, 
                  lead(obs, 60), NA))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to address your problem with a simple vector instead of a `data.frame`. It's easier to reason about, and will be easily adapted to a loop over a `data.frame`'s columns.

```
set.seed(2)
v <- runif(120) + 0.5
```

You can represent the "monthliness" of a vector by changing it to an array.

```
w <- matrix(v, nrow = 12)
w[, 1:3]
#            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#  [1,] 0.6848823 1.2605133 0.8472722
#  [2,] 1.2023740 0.6808201 0.9887732
#  [3,] 1.0733263 0.9052822 0.6492469
#  [4,] 0.6680519 1.3535485 0.8570626
#  [5,] 1.4438393 1.4763985 1.4626440
#  [6,] 1.4434750 0.7258255 0.6323720
#  [7,] 0.6291590 0.9448092 0.5104145
#  [8,] 1.3334488 0.5749794 0.6646422
#  [9,] 0.9680185 1.1618988 1.3101921
# [10,] 1.0499837 0.8875495 1.3688610
# [11,] 1.0526741 1.3368892 1.0142818
# [12,] 0.7388948 0.6505014 1.1271963
```

From your code, you want to make sure all values for the month within 5 years (including the original) are less than 1. So we can just compare 6 chunks of the matrix and combine the results.

```
total_cols <- ncol(w)
comparison <- {
  w[, 1:(total_cols - 5)] < 1 &
    w[, 2:(total_cols - 4)] < 1 &
    w[, 3:(total_cols - 3)] < 1 &
    w[, 4:(total_cols - 2)] < 1 &
    w[, 5:(total_cols - 1)] < 1 &
    w[, 6:(total_cols - 0)] < 1
}
comparison
#  [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#  [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [7,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [10,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [11,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [12,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Then we can create a new vector using the five-year ahead values based on which values of `comparison` are `TRUE`.

```
new_v <- rep(NA, length(v))
new_v[which(comparison)] <- w[, -(1:5)][which(comparison)]
new_v
#   [1]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 0.8881448
#   [8]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#  [15]        NA        NA        NA        NA 0.9026427        NA        NA
#  [22]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#  [29]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#  [36]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#  [43]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#  [50]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#  [57]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#  [64]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#  [71]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#  [78]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#  [85]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#  [92]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#  [99]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
# [106]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
# [113]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
```